# Constraints in snowflake database and performance

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've read the docs on Snowflake and realize Snowflake does not enforce constraints, except for not nulls.  However, does Snowflake use these constraints in any way to help optimize queries?

Comment: If the database does not enforce the constraints, then it would not be reasonable for the database to optimize assuming the unenforced constraints are true.

Comment: Since the constraints aren't enforced, the main benefit of adding them is so business intelligence and ETL platforms can import the relationships and unique constraints for their use.

Answer (score 2):

Check this Snowflake post by Kent Graziano:

- [RI (Referential Integrity) Constraints: 3 Reasons to Include Them in Your Data Warehouse](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/ri-in-your-data-warehouse-3-reasons/)

Basically these constraints are useful even when the database doesn't use the constraints, for reasons like:

1. Design Metadata (people and code trying to understand your schema)
2. BI Metadata (tools like Looker and Tableau can leverage this information)
3. Quality assurance (run checks to verify that the design is being respected)